# Does ES6 promises replace the need for async.js methods?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, async.js

With the introduction of http://es6-features.org/#PromiseUsage in ES6, is https://github.com/caolan/async still relevant? Do async.waterfall and async.series provide any benefit over promises?

Comment: Well sure, because they work with APIs designed around the callback(err, data) paradigm without needing adapters or promisifiers.

Comment: async.js is a vast tool suite and provides much more useful methods (especially for handling concurrency) than the builtin promise methods. But sure, you won't need anything like `waterfall` or `series` when working with promises.

Answer (score -1):

Yes and no. The async functions allow to just have it prepared for you rather then you building it yourself and the async still work everywhere. ES6 promises are pretty great. They allow to do a lot and when paired with the proposed ES7 async/await they might remove need for the package all together depending on how its implemented in the future.